# Storing exchange rates efficiently

Tags: 7, entities

I need to store a lot of data; the exchange rate for 42 currencies, every 15 minutes (collected via API). My current plan is to use a custom entity type (ECK) which simply stores the following properties (no fields):

- Datestamp
- Currency ID
- Exchange Rate

In a year, this would be 1.4 million entities. I wonder if I should do something more like this:

- Datestamp
- Rate For USD
- Rate for GBP
- Rate for CNY
- Rate for EUR ...

Which in a year would result in 35,000 entities. We will be adding more currencies overtime, so it would scale better too.

Which is the best method as far as Drupal is concerned (or maybe something else)? It will be used in to convert transactions from one currency to another, whilst retaining the exchange rate at time of transaction (hence the datestamp).

Thanks,
Paul.

Comment: The exchange rate is our own invention, used internally, so we unfortunately need to store it and not collect from elsewhere as required...

Comment: I don't think either option would be a bad option however it occurs to me that you don't need to store all the exchange rates over time, just the exchange rate at the time of transfer. So for current exchange rates you can just have a single entity for every currency. Then for every transaction, you store the exchange rate as it was at the time of the transaction on the transaction entity.

Comment: I did consider this, but the trouble being that I am (with any luck) going to have far more transactions per day than I am exchange rates so I think rates should be separated out.

Comment: If the datestamp is going to be your primary identifier, then you might as well go with your second option. I don't think it will make a huge difference. I suppose if you were worried about db bloat, you could periodically purge any dates that had no transactions?